# I'm testing WM_MENUCHAR but the code doesn't work as expected

Tags: c++, c, winapi

The example below uses an app window with just the System menu, and I'm trying to understand how the message `WM_MENUCHAR` is supposed to be used. The [MSDN doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646349(v=vs.85).aspx) for the message says:

> Sent when a menu is active and the user presses a key that does not correspond to any mnemonic or accelerator key. This message is sent to the window that owns the menu.

In the example below whenever I press the keys `Alt + A`, `Alt + B`, or whatever, the `WM_MENUCHAR` is sent to the window proc.

I'm assuming that the Alt key activates the system menu, since all the WM_MENUCHAR messages sent to `WndProc()` have `HIWORD(wParam) = MF_SYSMENU` and the reason why the message is sent to the window is due to the fact that the program doesn't have an accelerator table, nor does the system menu contains any mnemonic.

This is point that is not clear to me: in response to the `WM_MENUCHAR` the code returns `MAKELPARAM(5, MNC_SELECT)` but this return value doesn't invoke the `Close` menu item in the System menu (remember that 5 is the base-0 order number for this menu item in the System menu). What am I missing?

```
#include <windows.h>
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR pszCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX  wndclassx;

    wndclassx.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wndclassx.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wndclassx.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wndclassx.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wndclassx.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wndclassx.hInstance = hInstance;
    wndclassx.hIcon = 0;
    wndclassx.hCursor = LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW);
    wndclassx.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wndclassx.lpszClassName = L"WndProc";
    wndclassx.lpszMenuName = nullptr;
    wndclassx.hIconSm = 0;

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wndclassx)) return 0;

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindow(L"WndProc", L"WM_MENUCHAR", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_HSCROLL | WS_VSCROLL,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, 0, hInstance, 0);

    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_MAXIMIZE);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return (int)msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
        case WM_MENUCHAR:
        return MAKELPARAM(5, MNC_SELECT);

        case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

        default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is not clear why you'd want to do this at all, you don't have a menu.  DefWindowProc() already knows how to deal with the system menu.

Comment: @HansPassant I do have the system menu. if you click with the mouse right  button on the title bar you'll see it. `It is not clear why you'd want to do this at all` As I said, I'm just trying to understand how the message `WM_MENUCHAR` works.

Comment: Well, consider doing it right and create a menu.  Best way to find out what a real message handler should look like.

Comment: @HansPassant Well, the `WM_MENUCHAR` is being sent to my window proc. That certainly means something. Doesn't it?

Comment: That is why MF_SYSMENU is passed, tells you to do nothing. It is however technically possible to add items to the system menu so that is why you get the message. Nobody does this, users just don't expect the menu to look different or useful for something else.  There is a common example of a custom system menu, the console has one.  It adds the Edit, Defaults and Properties menu items.

Comment: @HansPassant You are not making sense. He does have a menu -- the system menu. This message is not for adding items to the menu, it is for handling custom accelerators not already handled by the system. And MF_SYSMENU is not passed to "tell you to do nothing", it's passed to tell you that lParam is a system menu handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MNC_SELECT merely "selects" the menu item specified by the low word, i.e. if you could see the menu that menu item would be highlighted. Seems pretty pointless, not sure what the use case is. If you wanted to actually invoke the menu item, you would use MNC_EXECUTE.

Additionally, the default "system menu" returned in lParam of the WM_MENUCHAR message apparently has only one item -- one that activates the actual system menu. In the actual system menu, the separator between "maximize" and "close" counts as a menu item, so the ordinal number of the "close" menu item is actually 6. So this code will do the following: if you press Alt+A and keep holding Alt, it will pop up the window system menu. If you then press A again, it will close the window.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    int count = 0;
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_MENUCHAR:
        count = GetMenuItemCount((HMENU)lParam);
        if (count == 1)
            return MAKELRESULT(0, MNC_EXECUTE);
        else
            return MAKELRESULT(6, MNC_EXECUTE);

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And the following I believe shows the full intended use of the message, including MNC_SELECT and MNC_EXECUTE. If you hold down Alt and keep pressing A it will pop up the system menu and highlight every item on it from top to bottom until it gets to the last item (typically "close") which it then executes. Note the weird noop between highlighting "maximize" and highlighting "close" when it "selects" the separator.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    int count = 0;
    static int selected = 1;
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_MENUCHAR:
        count = GetMenuItemCount((HMENU)lParam);
        if (count == 1)
            return MAKELRESULT(0, MNC_EXECUTE);
        else
        {
            if (selected < count)
                return MAKELRESULT(selected++, MNC_SELECT);
            else
                return MAKELRESULT(count - 1, MNC_EXECUTE);
        }

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried with `MNC_EXECUTE`, with `return MAKELPARAM(5, MNC_EXECUTE); `, but Windows doesn't send the corresponding `WM_COMMAND` message, neither does it execute the `Close` menu item.

Comment: I've updated the answer with something I did know myself until now.

Comment: I'm wondering where did you get this information?  But the answer makes a lot of sense to me. (+1)

Comment: @Ayrosa When you said MNC_EXECUTE did not work, I just debugged it a little bit. Win32 API is full of weird stuff like this, but I had never come across this before.

Comment: If you put a break at or before the execution of
`return MAKELRESULT(0, MNC_EXECUTE);` the system menu is **not** activated. I understand that the app window is deactivated with the break point, but I don't have a good explanation as to why the system menu is not shown when the app window gets reactivated, when the user presses `F5`.